# Keeping the connection alive for reading bulk data from .csv file

Tags: c#, .net, csv, hadoop, hbase

I have a .csv file with 2 million records and my target is to write it to the hbase database.

The code:

```
try { using (FileStream reader = File.OpenRead(@"C:\Data.csv")) 
            using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(reader))
            {
                parser.TrimWhiteSpace = true; // if you want
                parser.Delimiters = new[] { " " };
                parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;

                while (!parser.EndOfData)
                {
                    //Process the data
                       hbaseClient.StoreCells(hbaseTableName, set);
                 }
             } } catch(Exception e) {

}
```

After uploading the data of up to 800k records, I get a timeout exception. Is there anything which I can do avoid this timeout?

Answer (score 0):

Is this occuring everytime you do this operation. Try 2-3 times and see if it repeats. The fact that it happens after some records are added implies that something happened other than data issue. And timeout exception implies that the server could be down or due to network issues. Please try to repeat the same operation more times, and if error still persists, there should be another cause. Also please add entire exception stack trace, to gain better understanding